# using jquery and timepicker

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to use the timepicker in my asp.net project , I try to do the same thing in this link : https://timepicker.co

I download 2 files JS and CSS ,

but some like this , where can i put it ?

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
$('input.timepicker').timepicker({});});
```

and I would like to use some like this :

```
 $('.timepicker').timepicker({
timeFormat: 'h:mm p',
interval: 60,
minTime: '10',
maxTime: '6:00pm',
defaultTime: '11',
startTime: '10:00',
dynamic: false,
dropdown: true,
scrollbar: true });
```

but i dont have any idea of where can i put it.

this is my HTML code :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="Users/Myfile/Downloads/timepicker-1.3.5.zip/timepicker-1.3.5/jquery.timepicker.css">
    <script src="Users/Myfile/Downloads/timepicker-1.3.5.zip/timepicker-1.3.5/jquery.timepicker.js"></script>
    

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('input.timepicker').timepicker({});
        });
        </script>
<input type="text" class="timepicker" value=""/>
</head>
<body>
```

Comment: you missed `jquery.js` try to add jquery link

Comment: ` <script src="Users/Myfile/Downloads/timepicker-1.3.5.zip/timepicker-1.3.5/jquery.timepicker.js"></script>`
 already added

Comment: add this link in your head tag `<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>` or try the below answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add jquery link in your code it will be work's

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input.timepicker').timepicker({});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/timepicker/1.3.5/jquery.timepicker.min.css">
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/timepicker/1.3.5/jquery.timepicker.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" class="timepicker" value=""/>
```

Comment: Extra Question : how to get the id of input in Backend ? I try to get by id="" , it but no is not work

Comment: for that you have to add `runat="server"` for `input` then get by Id